# How can I adapt my VBA to include a second series of data

Tags: vba, excel

When I use the below macro it only works for one series data set. How can I adapt it so that I can include multiple series?

Currently if I try and use it to label a second set it will delete the first one and so on...

Thanks in advance

```
Sub AddXYLabels()
    If Left(TypeName(Selection), 5) <> "Chart" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the chart first."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set StartLabel = _
    Application.InputBox("Click on the cell containing the first(top) label", Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each pt In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
        pt.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue
        pt.DataLabel.Caption = StartLabel.Value
        Set StartLabel = StartLabel.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: please explain what you are currently doing, what is not working and what you like to achive.

Comment: It might work if you accessed the SeriesCollection Collection, and not the Points collection.
The code you have is only accessing the first series on the chart.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response. What I'm trying to do is add labels to every point on a bubble chart - however, the bubble chart has multiple series. The above code only works with charts that have a single series.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Like blckbird said, I'll need more information, if I have to come with a proper answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working for rest of the series since you have hard coded the range for only one series

```
For Each pt In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
```

Please try this

```css
Sub AddXYLabels()
If Left(TypeName(Selection), 5) <> "Chart" Then
MsgBox "Please select the chart first."
Exit Sub
End If
 Dim mySeries As Series
    Dim seriesCol As SeriesCollection
    Dim I As Integer
    I = 1
    Set seriesCol = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    For Each mySeries In seriesCol
        Set mySeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(I)
        With mySeries
            .ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue
                        
        End With
        I = I + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks :) - you're absolutely right, I had made it specific to the first data series.